# Entity Framework Core IEnumerable async

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have implemented a repository pattern in my project and have a `CoinRepository` and I want to add a new method (`GetValues`) which retrieves only one column (values) based on a condition from the Coin table which has multiple columns.

Here is the `CoinRepositopry` class and the method.

```
public class CoinRepository : Repository<Coin>, ICoinRepository
{
    public CoinRepository(MyContext context) : base(context) { }

    public IEnumerable<decimal> GetValuesAsync(int gameId, int gameTableId, string partnerCurrencyId)
    {
        return GetAllAsync().Result
            .Where(c => c.GameId == gameId && c.CurrencyId == partnerCurrencyId)
            .Select(c => c.Value);
    }
}
```

The `GetAllAsync` method is a method in the `IRepository` interface which returns a `Task <IEnumerable<Entity>>`.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
{
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        if (includeProperties != null)
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);

        if (orderBy != null)
            return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

My questions are:

1. Should I make the `GetValuesAsync` an `async` method?
2. Does the `GetAllAsync` method execute a query in the database and retrieve all the records, then apply the conditions in code - or does it execute the query in the database like this `SELECT c.value FROM COIN c WHERE <condition>` ?
3. If my code has problems and it is not fast enough, how can I modify it and refactor it in the most optimal way?

Thank you

Comment: 1. definitely, 2. if you convert the enumerable to list then it will have to enumerate everything, but if you don't and just return the queryable object then it will only read matching values.

Comment: *Should I make the GetValuesAsync an async method?* - if you **call it** `....Async` - then **YES**, by all means, make it async! Anything else would be a blatant violation of the Principle of Least Surprise

Comment: also why aren't you using the parameter filter? that was supposed to reduce the db load (since the query is executed at the end)

Comment: @Bizhan if i do make GetValuesAsync and async method and i do tolistasync at the end of the query should i change the return type to Task<List<decimal>> or i could leave it as Task<IEnumerable<decimal>> ?

Comment: @bizhan becasue it retrieves all columns and i just want the values column. how could i achieve that using the filter ?

Comment: you are doing `query = query.Where(filter);` and also you are doing `GetAllAsync().Result.Where`. Don't you think it's redundant? Not only that, it's highly inefficient as well.

Comment: @Artavazd as long as you're writing an `IQueryable` you filter will be evaluated on the db server and the query will only hold the matching elements. once you do a `Where` beyond this point (after materializing the query) its filtered on the web server

Comment: @Bizhan yes it is redundant, you are correct

Comment: and if you want (2) and (3) then you must filter your data BEFORE executing the query (which is done by applying ToList or similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I make the `GetValuesAsync` an `async` method?

Yes, definitely. Async propagates all the way up the call-stack. By accessing `Result` you're blocking the thread and defeating the purpose of async.

> Does the `GetAllAsync` method execute a query in the database, retrieve all the records and then apply the condition in the code or execute the query in the database like this `SELECT c.value FROM COIN c WHERE`?

You haven't provided an expression for `Where` so it will retrieve all rows from the database and filter in-memory.

> If my code has problems and it is not fast enough, how can I modify it and refactor it in the most optimal way?

```
public class CoinRepository : Repository<Coin>, ICoinRepository
{
    public CoinRepository(MyContext context) : base(context) { }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<decimal>> GetValuesAsync(int gameId, int gameTableId, string partnerCurrencyId)
    {
        var coins = await GetAllAsync(c => c.GameId == gameId && c.CurrencyId == partnerCurrencyId,
            includeProperties: nameof(Coin.Value));
        return coins.Select(c => c.Value);
    }
}
```

This way, you pass an expression to `GetAllAsync` which can be used to generate an SQL where clause, and specify only the `Value` column to retrieve.

Comment: why are you doing coins.Select(c => c.Value) if you already included the property "Value" ? isn't including the value property enough for selecting only the values?

Comment: @Artavazd Because that projects a collection of `Coin`s into a collection of `decimal`. The `includeProperties` instructs the database only to return what is required, but EF will still create `Coin` objects.

Comment: oh now I get it. really appreciate it.